# Multi-dimensional Javascript open array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have difficulty with assigning and retrieving the values of elements in the open array, the array size and dimensions are not fixed so its due to expand or shrink during the iteration.  I declare the array as `var NODES[[]];` trying to assign, retrieving values and obtaining the length of any dimension in array results wrong values. Especially with the `var le = NODES[0].length ;` code I 'd expect to see the total length of first dimension.

```
    var NODES =[[]]
    scene = editor.scene;
    scene.traverse( function(e) {

    if ( (e instanceof THREE.Line) && (e.name = 'main line' ) )
    {

        for (i=0; i<e.geometry.vertices.length; i++){

            var x = e.position.x+ e.geometry.vertices[i].x
            var y = e.position.y+ e.geometry.vertices[i].y
            var z = e.position.z+ e.geometry.vertices[i].z      

            NODES[node_cnt,0] = x;
            NODES[node_cnt,1] = y;
            NODES[node_cnt,2] = z;
            node_cnt++;
        }

     cnt++;      

    }; 
    var le = NODES[0].length ;


EXPECTED RESULT 
NODES[0][0] = 10; NODES[0][1] = 20;  NODES[0][3] = 30; 
NODES[1][0] = 40; NODES[1][1] = 50;  NODES[1][3] = 60; 
NODES[2][0] = 70; NODES[2][1] = 80;  NODES[2][3] = 90; 

with `var le = NODES[0].length ;` I expect to see 3 because I'm requesting the length of 1st dimension
```

Comment: And what is wrong here? Except `NODES[node_cnt,0]`

Comment: The whole structure of array is not producing the correct values, its not allocating the 2D array, I set breakpoint to monitor the array and there I can see that array is never construed as 2D, which was my intention.

Comment: why are you doing `NODES[node_cnt,0]`? each of those lines is going to be equivalent to `NODES[0]`,`NODES[1]`,`NODES[2]`

Comment: I changed it to `NODES[node_cnt][0] = x;` without any remarkable effect

Comment: I believe that I'm not correctly allocating the open array in proper javascript syntax, it resembles to the nested array in standalone compilers where the array is open ended but I'm not sure whether its valid in javascript.

Comment: I also added the expected result in the original post.

Comment: the problem is not fully understanding the comma operator ....`NODES[node_cnt,2]` is not the same as `NODES[node_cnt][2]` it is equivalent to `NODES[2]`..... Changing to `NODES[node_cnt][2]` would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the javascript interpretation of multi dimensional array, NODES is an array which contains actually 3 array, every array contained in NODES contain a string:

```
    var NODES = [[],[],[]];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
        NODES[0].push(i + 'x');
        NODES[1].push(i + 'y');
        NODES[2].push(i + 'z');


    }
    console.log(NODES[0].lenght);
```

If every contained array should contain one another array the sintax to do this should be:

```
    NODES[0].push([i + 'x']);
```

Sorry, I'm not understand clearly what mean `node_cnt` and `cnt`, but I think you should do something like this:

```
var NODES =[[],[],[]]
    scene = editor.scene;
    scene.traverse( function(e) {

    if ( (e instanceof THREE.Line) && (e.name = 'main line' ) )
    {

        for (i=0; i<e.geometry.vertices.length; i++){

            var x = e.position.x+ e.geometry.vertices[i].x
            var y = e.position.y+ e.geometry.vertices[i].y
            var z = e.position.z+ e.geometry.vertices[i].z      

            NODES[0].push(x);
            NODES[1].push(y);
            NODES[2].push(z);
            node_cnt++;
        }

     cnt++;      

    }; 
    var le = NODES[0].length ;
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense now, let me play around with it a bit more and I'll acccept it as answer.